# pymongo : delete records elegantly

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here is my code to delete a bunch of records using pymongo

```
ids = []
with MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST) as connection:
    db = connection[MONGODB_NAME]
    collection = db[MONGODN_COLLECTION]
    for obj in collection.find({"date": {"$gt": "2012-12-15"}}):
        ids.append(obj["_id"])
    for id in ids:
        print id
        collection.remove({"_id":ObjectId(id)})
```

IS there a better way to delete these records? like delete a whole set of records directly

```
collection.find({"date": {"$gt": "2012-12-15"}}).delete() or remove()
```

or delete from obj like

```
 obj.delete() or obj.remove()
```

or somehting similar?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
collection.remove({"date": {"$gt": "2012-12-15"}})
```

Comment: if you know the id, you can simply `collection.remove(dupId)`

Comment: Note that `collection.remove(dupId)` expects an `ObjectId('some-hex-id')` rather than just the `'some-hex-id'` string

Comment: Python 3, Mongo 3.6:
`result = collection.delete_many({"date": {"$gt": "2012-12-15"}})`
`print(f'{result.deleted_count} docs deleted')`

Answer (score 13):

For now `collection.remove(filter)` is deprecated, use `collection.delete_many(filter)`.

Example: `collection.delete_many({"author": ObjectId("...")})`